# Displaying tweets problem with @username

Tags: twitter

I'm getting a problem displaying tweets that include reply's (ie when you @username someone). It's showing the @ symbol but then cutting off the rest of the tweet. (Check out [www.teamworksdesign.com](http://www.teamworksdesign.com) in the bottom right hand corner)

Can anyone help with this or suggest a good plugin?

```
<?php

function parseTweet($text) {
$pattern_url = '~(?>[a-z+]{2,}://|www\.)(?:[a-z0-9]+(?:\.[a-z0-9]+)?@)?(?:(?:[a-z](?:[a-z0-9]|(?<!-)-)*[a-z0-9])(?:\.[a-z](?:[a-z0-9]|(?<!-)-)*[a-z0-9])+|(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?))(?:/[^\\/:?*"|\n]*[a-z0-9])*/?(?:\?[a-z0-9_.%]+(?:=[a-z0-9_.%:/+-]*)?(?:&[a-z0-9_.%]+(?:=[a-z0-9_.%:/+-]*)?)*)?(?:#[a-z0-9_%.]+)?~i';
'@([A-Za-z0-9_]+)';
$tweet = preg_replace('/(^|\s)#(\w+)/', '\1#<a
href="http://search.twitter.com/search?q=%23\2″ rel="nofollow">\2</a>', $text);
$tweet = preg_replace('/(^|\s)@(\w+)/', '\1@<a
href="http://www.twitter.com/\2″ rel="nofollow">\2</a>', $tweet);
$tweet = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])(([\w]+?://[\w\#$%&~.\-;:=,?@\[\]+]*)(/[\w\#$%&~/.\-;:=,?@\[\]+]*)?)#is", "\\1<a
href=\"\\2\" title=\"\\2\" rel=\"nofollow\">[link]</a>", $tweet);
return $tweet;
}

$username='teamworksdesign'; // set user name
$format='json'; // set format
$tweet=json_decode(file_get_contents("http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/{$username}.{$format}")); // get tweets and decode them into a variable

$theTweet = parseTweet($tweet[0]->text);
$newTweet = substr($theTweet,0,65);
echo '<a class="tweet" rel="nofollow" href="http://www.twitter.com/teamworksdesign"> "' . $newTweet . '..."</a>';

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi Rob@:try with this plugin [Tweet This](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tweet-this/screenshots/).you can set your custom image also.:)

or

Try this code...

Open the sidebar.php
Locate the “twitter-feed” div

```
<div class=”twitter-feed”>
<h2>What I’m up to…</h2>
<ul id=”twitter_update_list”></ul>
<script type=”text/javascript” src=”http://twitter.com/javascripts/blogger.js”></script>
<script type=”text/javascript” src=”http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/JunLoayza.json?callback=twitterCallback2&amp;count=1″></script>
<div class=”follow-on-twitter”>
<a rel=”nofollow” href=”">Follow me on Twitter</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Replace with Twitter username

```
<script type=”text/javascript” src=”http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/AddYourUsernameHere.json?callback=twitterCallback2&amp;count=1″></script>
```

Now you will want to add your twitter URL to the “Follow me on Twitter” link.  The following code is listed in blue above:

```
<a rel=”nofollow” href=”http://Twitter.com/AddYourUsernameHere“>Follow me on Twitter</a>
```

The final code

```
<div class=”twitter-feed”>
<h2>What I’m up to…</h2>
<ul id=”twitter_update_list”></ul>
<script type=”text/javascript” src=”http://twitter.com/javascripts/blogger.js”></script>
<script type=”text/javascript” src=”http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/AddYourUsernameHere.json?callback=twitterCallback2&amp;count=1″></script>
<div class=”follow-on-twitter”>
<a rel=”nofollow” href=”http://Twitter.com/AddYourUsernameHere“>Follow me on Twitter</a>
</div>
</div>
```

save and run :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The reason I went with the code above was to strip all the unecessary stuff out, will that plugin allow me to just display the tweet and nothing else?

Answer (score 2):

That is one nasty regexp. I would suggest looking into [Twitter entities](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/tweet_entities) instead, much easier than trying to parse it yourself.

And this really has little to do with WP and more suitable for other sites in network.

Comment: Cheers, shall try it out. p.s The reason it's on here is if there's a good working plugin then I'll use it instead.

Comment: @Rob then update your question to mention that alternatively you are looking for a plugin and what that plugin should be able to do.